# All system font turned into boxes or missing

Tags: fonts

I accidentally changed fonts.config, which shouldn't be changed. After the change all system font is turned into boxes or missing. But chrome works fine (websites). I tried sudo fc-cache -r -v and reboot but no changes. Is there any way to fix that? To Restore font.config?

Comment: If you boot from a live USB, can you change the file back to what it was before?

Comment: Yeah, I boot from external SSD.  I will reinstall it, I was planning to do anyway.